# Showing :name from signup form in profiles form using Devise in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, foreign-keys

I need my App to be able to display `:name` from the sign up form in the `profiles/new _form` is that possible? and how?

When my User sign up for an account via Devise they sign up by inserting `:name`, `email`and `password`. Like seen in the code below:

```
<div class="row img-back">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
  <div class="well sign-up-form">
   <h2>Ný skráning</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :Nafn_fyrirtækis_stofnunar %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>


  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :tölvu_póstfang %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control'  %>
  </div>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :Lykilorð %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(Minnst <%= @minimum_password_length %> stafir )</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control'  %>
  </div>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :Staðfesting_lykilorðs %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control'  %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Ný skrá", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

</div>
```

After Sign up the user is directed to the `views/profiles/new.html.erb` with this method in `registrations_controller.rb`

```
 def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  new_user_profile_path(current_user) 
 end
```

And in the `views/profiles/new.html.erb` the user fills in a `_form.html.erb` partial to finish its profile and register all the information the app needs to work for the user.

this is the `_form.html.erb`

```
%= form_for @profile, url: user_profile_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :name %>
                    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :avatar %>
                    <%= f.file_field :avatar, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :staff %>
                    <%= f.number_field :staff, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :building_size %>
                    <%= f.number_field :building_size, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :address %>
                    <%= f.text_field :address, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :postalcode %>
                    <%= f.text_field :postalcode, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :website%>
                    <%= f.text_field :website, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :contact_person %>
                    <%= f.text_field :contact_person, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :contact_email %>
                    <%= f.email_field :contact_email, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :phone_number %>
                    <%= f.text_field :phone_number, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :buisness_type %>
                    <%= f.select :buisness_type,['Þjónusta', 'Ráðgjöf', 'Verlsun', 'Stofnun', 'Annað'], class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :description %>
                    <%= f.text_area :description, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.submit "Update Profile", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
                </div>

            <% end %>
```

My `profile.rb` `belongs_to :user`and my `user.rb` model `has_one :profile`

**EDIT** according to jsw324 answer
Here is the  `profiles_controller.rb`

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!

#before_action :only_current_user

def new
    #form where a user can fill put their pwn profile.

    @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) # Finnur hver er userinn sem er loggaður inn, reaching in to the url and grabbs user.
    @profile = Profile.new
    @profile.name = current_user.name


end

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    #@profile = @user.profile
    @profile.name = current_user.name

end

def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @profile = @user.build_profile(profile_params)

    #Lecture 159 User show action next :))))
    if @profile.save
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
        redirect_to user_path(params[:user_id]) #fer á user/show.html.erb
    else
        render action: :new

    end

end

def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @profile = @user.profile

end

def update
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @profile = @user.profile


    if @profile.update_attributes(profile_params)
        flash[:success] = "Profile Updated!"
        redirect_to user_path(params[:user_id])
    else
        render action :edit
    end     
end


private

    def profile_params
        params.require(:profile).permit(:name, :staff, :address, :postalcode, :website, :contact_person, :contact_email, :phone_number, :buisness_type, :description, :building_size, :avatar)
    end

    def only_current_user

        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user
    end
```

And I edited this line in the `views/profiles/_form.html.erb`

```
    <%= form_for @profile, url: user_profile_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %> 

    <div class="row">
     <div class="container">
       <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :Name %>
                    <%= f.name %>

                </div>
```

Now I get this Error: `undefined method`name' for #`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh. You need to handle that in the controller. Something like `@profiles.name = current_user.name`.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll check it out tomorrow, must go to sleep now, thanks.... I mark it answered if it works :)

Comment: Thanks, let me know. Get some rest :)

Comment: Hi, I'm awake :) I modified my code according to your answer, I get a new error now, can you please take a look at my Edit to the question?? thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, you can use 'f.name' in the view to display the name, was late last night for me too :)   You have a name column in your profile table right?  lmk how that works.

Comment: sorry, this might sound stupid, but were in the text field would I put `f.name`? And Yes, there is a :name column in the profiles table

Comment: if you don't want the user to have the ability to edit their name you can replace '<%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field @profiles.name, class: 'form-control' %>' these 2 lines with <%= f.name %> -- assuming you have a name column in your profile table.  Additionally - take the 's' off of '@profile' if that's your instance variable.  Last, log on to a rails console and play with it.  Set User.first to a variable and set Profile.first to a variable, check the value of Profile.name and User.name make sure they're behaving correctly.

Comment: This is working now  I just had to modify the `new` method in the `profiles_controller` See my Edits..... Thank you so much :)

Comment: In your view you have :Name with the 'n' capitalized but that's not the issue. When you're in the console, can you confirm that Profile.name exists?

Comment: Yes, it all works now.... I was working in the `show`method instead of the `new`method in the profiles_controller......I guess I need a coffee :) thank you so much

Comment: Hey, can you please mark this is answered?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand but to display the name you can just use <%= current_user.name %> wherever you need it.

Comment: Sorry, I have to use it in this line instead of :name,                              `<div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
     </div>`                                                                        it basically have to go the :name in the profile model, so after the sign up the name that the user added in the Devise form appears in the profile form and gets saved to the database as a part of the profile table